# Drop row in a data frame if value has less than 2 decimal places

Tags: r, regex, subset, extract

In one column of a data frame, I have values for longitude. For example:

`df<-data.frame(long=c(-169.42000,144.80000,7.41139,-63.07000,-62.21000,14.48333,56.99900))`

I want to keep rows which have at least three decimal places (i.e three non-zero values immediately after the decimal point) and delete all others. So rows 1,2,4 and 5 would be deleted from `df` in the example above.

So far I've tried using`grep` to extract the rows I want to keep:

`new.df<-df[-grep("000$",df$long),]`

However this has deleted all rows. Any ideas? I'm new to using grep so there may be glaring errors that I've not picked up on!

Many thanks!

Comment: As @Roland 's answer points out, this is heavily dependent on whether your treat your values as  **strings** or **numeric** values.  Because of the limitations on floating-point representations, you need to examine rounded versions of your values.  If you use purely strings, then regex will be trustworthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify your regular expression slightly. The following one select all values with three non-zero numbers after the decimal point:

```
new.df <- df[grep("\\.[1-9][1-9][1-9]", df$long), ]
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use regex for this.

```
tol <- .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5
#use tol <- 0.001 to get the same result as with the regex for numbers like 0.9901
discard <- df$long-trunc(df$long*100)/100 < tol
df[!discard, , drop=FALSE]
#       long
# 3  7.41139
# 6 14.48333
# 7 56.99900
```